# Multiple 'in' operators in Python?

Tags: python

**Is there a shorthand way of checking for keys in a dictionary?**

Something that I can use instead of using multiple `in` and `and` operators - instead of the following:

```
('somekey' in d) and ('someotherkey' in d) and ('somekeyggg' in d)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this?  It looks very clear and elegant.

Comment: It gets annoying if you have to do it for 8 or 9 keys.

Comment: Then consider showing that as the example.  The three key version isn't bad, and doesn't demonstrate any real problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
all( word in d for word in [ 'somekey', 'someotherkey', 'somekeyggg' ] )
```

Comment: @Gareth: why did you add that split?

Comment: @reno sorry to pick nits, but I believe that would be a [generator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) [expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Comment: This should be changed back to its original form. No reason for the edit.

Comment: @Gareth: You can explain in your own answer why you think using a string and `split()` is better, but I see no reason to change the other answers to follow this approach.

Comment: @Marty: Not really a nit you're picking here: the generator expression short-circuits on the first `word` that's not in `d`. A list comprehension will create the entire list of boolean values before calling the `all` function. This is a really cool feature of using `all()` and `any()` with generator expressions.

Answer (score 5):

```
set(['somekey', 'someotherkey', 'somekeyggg']).issubset(d)
```